# Freemarker Looking For Default Templates

Tags: java, html, struts2, freemarker

I set up a template directory through struts.ui.templateDir in my struts.xml. Now, when I access my page, a java.io.FileNotFoundException comes up looking for a bunch of files that I can only guess Freemarker is looking for by default.

Here is one such file:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: Template /WEB-INF/templates/simple/form-close.ftl not found.
```

I do not want this file or any other file other than the templates I create to be looked for. Is there some way to prevent Freemarker from doing this? Also, where is there documentation for this library? I cannot seem to find anything other than blog sites...

Comment: Documentation for which library?

Comment: Freemarker. I think I found one, it seems horribly outdated though...

Comment: Not sure I understand; what FreeMarker docs are you looking for? The latest version is 2.3.18, both the user guide and API docs are on the FreeMarker site.

Comment: Or do you mean the S2 templating docs? Nothing about that has changed in quite some time; there's nothing to update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basicly any struts-tag uses one or more *.ftl to render a specific tag to the page (they are required).

You cant 'just remove' some of the templates. If you want to write your own templates, copy all ftls from the struts jar (templates.simple) to your template dir. Then replace the ftls you want to change.

Overriding struts.xml is not nessecary most of the time, you can also set your template path and standard theme via struts.properties.

```
### Standard UI theme
struts.ui.theme=xhtml
struts.ui.templateDir=template
```

Update to your comment: I thought, you want to provide your own templates. But you can also specify the 'theme' property for the struts tags to change a single ftl for any tag.

```
<s:select name="myName" theme="myTheme" />
```

Then create your select.ftl and add it under src/main/resources/template/myTheme.

Comment: Well I didn't want to change a particular ftl, I wanted to add my own custom one.

Comment: I'm attempting to add a custom template I can access through struts component tag. I'm I going about this incorrectly?

Comment: I've updated my answer about how to use a custom template for a single tag.